# css not updating after href change of <link> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

Ok so I'm fairly new to programming and I'm searching for a solution to the following: I'm trying to update the css of my page on the fly, using JQuery to change the 'href' value in the link tag.

I'm using a simple testcase to try to get it working. I'm using Less for CSS. 
I have 2 .less files ('test.less' & 'testTwo.less'). This is my code:

```js
$(function() {

 $('#changeButton').click(function() {
  $('#style').attr('href', '../testfiles/testTwo.less');
  console.log($('#style').attr('href'));
 })

})
```

I log the href value to see if it actually changes, which it does. Only the styling of the page won't change.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/less" href="../testfiles/test.less" id="style">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="changeButton">click me</div>

    <script src="../bower_components/less/dist/less.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm definitely missing something here, something I don't know yet about css rendering I suppose. Any help is welcome, thanks! :).

Comment: It seems when you change the source, the less compiler does not come in action which explains the issue.

Comment: its in a race it seems.. less is is not in action when that fires

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there any possibility to recompile the css after a change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code to following

```
$(function() {

    $('#changeButton').click(function() {
        $('#style').attr('href', '../testfiles/testTwo.less');
        console.log($('#style').attr('href'));
        $('style[id^="less:"]').remove(); // you need to remove the less
        less.refresh(); // refresh the files
    })

})
```

**Notes**

1. It is preferred to have css in html in place of less (performance impact). Use pre compilers at let the html refer to css.
2. Less compiler does not  automatically compile dynamically added files. You need to force less compiler to refresh styles.
3. You need to remove the less due to the way LESS works. It parses the less file, and then adds a style attribute to the DOM with id attribute as `id='less:<<NAME OF YOUR LESS FILE>>'`

Comment: Now less refresh will start compiling all the less files in the page which will be an performance hit.

Comment: @abs - I totally agree with you. That is why I have added notes for the same.

Comment: Hmm maybe it's just me but this doesn't seem to do it. Console says it has loaded the new less file successfully and rendered the new css in 20ms, but there's not change on the page.

Comment: @StijnVVL - Can you share some code i.e. plunker/fiddle etc

Comment: This is to a jsFiddle but it appears less is not really cooperating... https://jsfiddle.net/3wz2Lwzq/4/

Comment: @StijnVVL - I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: @nikhil Thank you very much! I'll try this in a second. For now I got it working with a css precompiler SimpLESS I needed to download first. It changes every less file into css, which does the trick. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we are using `less.js` all the less file should be loaded before that so that it can compile the less files to css during page load. Since you are adding the less file dynamically  it wont get a chance to compile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do you suggest I do in this case?

Comment: I would suggest instead of loading less file load the css files. When you do the development compile it to a css file and load that css files. which will be faster

Comment: I've compiled the less files to css files using simpLESS. It works now although there is a small delay in the change. Thank you for your help!